# How to print the butterfly pattern using C++?

Tags: c++

So I am taking  a C++ course during which I was asked to write a program to print the following butterfly pattern:

```
*      *
**    **
***  ***
********
********
***  ***
**    **
*      *
```

So, this is what I wrote:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    int n;
    cin>>n;

    for(int row=1; row<=n; row++){
        for(int j=1; j<=2*n; j++){
            if(j<=row||j>=(2*n)-row){
                cout<<"*";
            
            }
            else{
                cout<<" ";
            }
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    for(int row=n; row>0; row--){
        for(int j=1; j<=2*n; j++){
            if(j<=row||j>=(2*n)-row){
                cout<<"*";
            
            }
            else{
                cout<<" ";
            }
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but I couldn't get the desired result. What could be the reason?

Comment: What did the debugger tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition `j>=(2*n)-row` is wrong.

You will want to make `row` characters from left and `row` characters from right to be `*` and the other characters to be space.

For example, let's consider `row=1` case.

Considering "from left" part, the condition `j<=row` is correct and it will be true in one situration `j=1`.

On the other hand, considering "from right" part, the condition `j>=(2*n)-row` will be true in two siturations `j=2*n-1` and `j=2*n`.

To fix this issue, you should reduce number of `*` from right by one.

This can be done by changing the condition (both two of them) to `j>=(2*n)-(row-1)`.